# Replace string in a file with string from sub line

Tags: windows, string, shell, replace

Hello all i have an issue.
i have an automatic txt file generated everyday from external company. and i have a bug when i want to load it into my system, so end users need to rewrite the file manually.

So i need to create a script with the following goal.

for each line which start by  `:86:/TYPE/0040/`

i need to replace  `/TYPE/0040` by the value of the next line starting by `/OCMT`

example

```
86:/TYPE/0040/VOR ETRANGE /  ==> 86:/OCMT/EUR2405,/VOR ETRANGE /
```

thanks a lot for any support
script must run on Windows os.

this is an example of the file, where I have more than 2000 lines

```
##################
:86:/TYPE/0040/VOR ETRANGE /
/ORDP/GALAK CHEZ MAMANLDA
/ORDP/PT
/REMI/TOTOT TATA
/OCMT/EUR2405,/
/EFEE/EUR0,/
:86:/TYPE/0568/VOR/
/REMI//ADV/260050000002 15.1.2015
/ETEI/7026150001
/ORDP/SOC DES POUBELLES
:61:1000000005C20546,28NTRFNONREF//15014215
:86:/TYPE/0568/VOR /
/REMI/00000 0000000 0000000
/ETEI/VIREMENT OREXAD
/ORDP/ORETOPEZZ
:86:/TYPE/0040/VOR toto/
/ORDP/ADVANCED  +
/ORDP/US
/REMI/200000000559ISCW APDORTSB
/OCMT/USD37500,/
/EFEE/EUR0,/
##################
```

Comment: It seems to be a SWIFT message. You can process it with cmd. See `FOR /F %var (file-set) do ...` (read `for /?`) and you need string manipulation (read `set /?`). Not the easiest, but doable. Or install [tag:cygwin] and use [tag:bash] or [tag:awk].

Comment: thanks a lot    i can try it .            if you have an idea with awk i am interrested

Comment: I added s pure windows cmd solution. Pls. check it!

Answer (score 0):

I think I could make it! It is pure [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) version (No [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) involved). Here is the not trivial solution (I assume that the input file is called `conv.txt`):

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM Read all lines and store OCMT values in environment variables
set REF=
REM set line=0
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/" %%i IN (conv.txt); DO (
  SET /A line += 1
  REM echo !line!: %%i, %%j, %%k
  set type=%%i
  if "!type:~0,1!" == ":" set REF=
  IF "%REF%" == "" (
    IF "%%i" == ":86:" IF "%%j" == "TYPE" IF "%%k" == "0040" set REF=!line!
  )   
  if "%%i" == "OCMT" set OCMT_!!REF!!=%%j
)


REM Read all lines again and replace
set line=0
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%i IN (conv.txt); DO (
  SET /A line += 1
  set LL=%%i
  IF "!LL:~0,15!" == ":86:/TYPE/0040/" (
    FOR /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%a IN ('set OCMT_!line!') DO (
      set LL=:86:/OCMT/%%b/!LL:~15!
    )
  )
  echo !LL!
)
```

Output:

```
 ##################
:86:/OCMT/EUR2405,/VOR ETRANGE /
/ORDP/GALAK CHEZ MAMANLDA
/ORDP/PT
/REMI/TOTOT TATA
/OCMT/EUR2405,/
/EFEE/EUR0,/
:86:/TYPE/0568/VOR/
/REMI//ADV/260050000002 15.1.2015
/ETEI/7026150001
/ORDP/SOC DES POUBELLES
:61:1000000005C20546,28NTRFNONREF//15014215
:86:/TYPE/0568/VOR /
/REMI/00000 0000000 0000000
/ETEI/VIREMENT OREXAD
/ORDP/ORETOPEZZ
:86:/OCMT/USD37500,/VOR toto/
/ORDP/ADVANCED  +
/ORDP/US
/REMI/200000000559ISCW APDORTSB
/OCMT/USD37500,/
/EFEE/EUR0,/
##################
```

It parses the input file twice. First block reads the file and sets an environment variable `OCMT_<TYPE_LINE>=<OCMT LINE AMOUNT>` (eg. `OCMT_2=EUR2405,`). In the second block it finds again the lines starting with `:86:/TYPE/0040/`. Then it replaces with `:86:/OCMT/<OCMT LINE AMOUNT>/<rest of the line>`.

The main trick was how to get back the environment variables. It was solved be the internal `FOR` loop calling `set` in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd).

This is not a complete solution! Not all possible error is checked and handled (e.g. only `:86:/TYPE/0040/...` lines may contain `OCMT` sublines? Could it have empty lines?), but it fits to the brief specification...

I hope this helps!